# MVC5: Check DropDownList for having Selection (InvalidOperationException)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5, invalidoperationexception

I am using [BootStrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) to show/hide 2 `Html.DropDownLists()` on one of my MVC5/EF6 Project Views:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="12345" name="Sponsor-Organization" checked class="userCreate-BSSwitch" />

        <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
            <div class="row switchOn">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberOrgId, "Organization")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList("MemberOrgId", ViewData["Organization"] as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "MemberOrgId" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberOrgId)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row switchOff">
                <dliv class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId, "Sponsor")
                </dliv>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SponsorOrgId", ViewData["Sponsor"] as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SponsorOrgId" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SponsorOrgId)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { $("#alert").alert('close'); }, 5000);
        $('.switchOff').addClass('hide');

    });
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.state = '';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onText = 'Member';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offText = 'Sponsor';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offColor = 'info';
    $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.animate = false;

    //$.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.size = 'large';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').bootstrapSwitch();
    });

    $('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
        var checked = state;
        if (checked) {
            $('.switchOn').removeClass('hide');
            $('.switchOff').addClass('hide');
            $('#SponsorOrgId').val("");
        }
        else {
            $('.switchOff').removeClass('hide');
            $('.switchOn').addClass('hide');
            $('#MemberOrgId').val("");
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-danger").click(function () {
            var cancel = confirm("Are you sure? Entered data will be lost.")
            if (cancel != true) {
                event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event
            }
        });
    });

    //$('input:checkbox[name="Sponsor-Organization"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
</script>
```

Controller **Create()** Method:

```
        // POST: Admin/UserManagement/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,property1, property2, etc...")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
        {
            if ((applicationUser.MemberOrgId == null) && (applicationUser.SponsorOrgId == null))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Must select either an Organization or Sponsor from the dropdown lists.");
                return View(applicationUser);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.headerTitle = "Create User";
                applicationUser.UserName = applicationUser.Email;
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, "r@nd0mP@$S");
                if (result.Succeeded) 
                {
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserManagement");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to Create User.");
                    var errors = string.Join(",", result.Errors);
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", errors);
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to Create User.");
            var errors1 = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors }).ToString();
            ModelState.AddModelError("", errors1);

            ViewData["Organization"] = new SelectList(db.MemberOrganizations, "Id", "Name", applicationUser.MemberOrgId);
            ViewData["Sponsor"] = new SelectList(db.SponsorOrganizations, "Id", "Name", applicationUser.SponsorOrgId);
            if (applicationUser.MemberOrgId != null)
            {
                ViewBag.SwitchState = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.SwitchState = false;
            }
            ViewBag.OrganizationId = new SelectList(db.MemberOrganizations, "Id", "State", applicationUser.MemberOrgId);

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(applicationUser);

        }
```

This enables me to ensure that ONLY 1 of the DropDownList's have a selection made as I clear the current selection when the current DropDownList is hidden via my JavaScript. What I need now is a way to make sure a selection has been made in the currently displayed list before saving the new Identity User to the database.

Now, my Controller correctly identifies when no selection has been made in either list:

```
if ((applicationUser.MemberOrgId == null) && (applicationUser.SponsorOrgId == null))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Must select either an Organization or Sponsor from the dropdown lists.");
                return View(applicationUser);
            }
```

However, when the View is returned, instead of Model State error I am immediately receiving the below at code line `@Html.DropDownList("MemberOrgId", ViewData["Organization"] as SelectList, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "MemberOrgId" })`:

```
InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MemberOrgId'.
```

Anyone have thoughts on how to better handle this?